# Expressing the sign pattern $+--++--+\cdots$ in a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, power-series, taylor-expansion

I had to find the Taylor series for the function $f(x)=\cos(x)$ centred at $a=\frac{\pi}{4}$.

I found the pattern but the only part I'm missing is the sign. Since the series is centred at $\frac{\pi}{4}$, no value of $f^{\{n\}}(a)$ is equal to zero, and the pattern is $+, -, -, +, +, -, -, +$.

I have checked the answer that my teacher put in the document, but he just wrote

> $$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\text{sign} \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2(n!)}}\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)^n$$
>   here $\text{sign} =+--++--++--+ \cdots$

which I find rather disappointing...

> Is there a mathematical way to insert the sign pattern into the series, similarly to $(-1)^n$ for a normal alternating series?

Comment: you could split up the sum into 2 alternating series

Comment: Sometimes readability is to be preferred imho

Comment: Notice that that's the sign pattern for cosine as we cycle counterclockwise through the quadrants. This suggests considering the $\pi/4$ angles in each quadrant: $$\sqrt{2}\cos\left(\frac\pi4+n\frac\pi2\right)=\sqrt{2}\cos\left((2n+1)\frac\pi4\right)$$ where the multiplied $\sqrt{2}$ makes the terms unit-sized ... and, conveniently, helps simplify the rest of the expression in the summation.

Answer (score 5):

What about $$\frac{\cos(\pi/4+n\pi/2)}{\cos(\pi/4)}$$

Comment: You start with something simple: $+ - - + + - -+\cdots$, and you turn it into something that makes your readers scratch their heads and reach for pencil and paper...

Comment: Agreed. Although my answer wants to be geometric and is well represented by Blue's comment: in the sense that the looked-for sign sequence is $+--+$, which is exactly the sequence in which cosine changes sign as we let the angle increase.

Answer (score 5):

One simple method that clearly shows your intentions is:
$$(-1)^{\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor}$$
Mathematically cleaner, but not so transparent:
$$(-1)^{\frac12n(n+1)}$$
Having said that, your teacher's method is easier to read than either of these solutions.

Comment: I like the top one. It is almost acceptable to actually use that.